# need guidance on strategy for creating typescript public type definitions

Tags: typescript, aurelia

i am seeking guidance on creating public type definitions for the aurelia framework - [aurelia on github here](https://github.com/aurelia/) / [aurelia website here](http://aurelia.io/) / [aurelia typescript samples on github](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript)

i am struggling with the following pattern:

[image: repository pattern]

typescript compiler wont allow export declaration in an ambient external module declaration that references an external module through relative external module name

the repos use systemjs and jspm to resolve aurelia-metadata. i want to use ambient module declarations to expose the types from aurelia-metadata

what i'm trying to achieve is effectively the same as copying the contents of origin.d.ts, resource-type.d.ts, and metadata.d.ts into the ambient module declaration in aurelia.d.ts.

note that ./metadata/index.js basically publishes the public interface through its exports, and that is precisely what i want to expose in the ambient module declaration

i could surrender and manually copy the info from the compiler-generated origin.d.ts, resource-type.d.ts, and metadata.d.ts into the ambient module declaration, but have been trying to find a way to just expose what is exported in index.d.ts, as that is the public api for the module in the repo.

the issue with the manual approach is that there are already 20+ libraries, they will continue to grow, and if updating the api can't be done using the compiler, i will be forever tracking the changes in the repos and updating the api manually.

i believe that the public api for each repo must be an ambient module because the actual path to the corresponding import (aurelia-metadata in this case) is resolved using systemjs loader (the module dependencies are managed using jspm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `origin.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'aurelia/origin' {
    export class Origin {
    }
}
```

You can import / reexport it as `aurelia.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./origin/origin.d.ts"/>
declare module 'aurelia' {
    export * from 'aurelia/origin';
}
```

---

Verified from usage:

```
/// <reference path="./aurelia"/>

import {Origin as Origin1} from "aurelia/origin";
import {Origin as Origin2} from "aurelia";
```

Note: the *exact* answer depend on how you want to use the definitions in Typescript.

Tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2516#issuecomment-87509666